# Accessing parent controller from child controller (form buttons) AngularJS 1.5

Tags: angularjs

Here is my situation:

I have a component, the view of which renders a "save" and "cancel" button.  The buttons are related to a single input field which a user clicks "edit" to edit the value (or cancel the edit).

The original implementation had the three buttons in its view as shown here:

```
 <div class="input-edit input-no-border" ng-show="!$ctrl.editingTitle && !$ctrl.isSaving">
                    <input type="text" ng-value="$ctrl.knowledgeHubSection.title" class="field" readonly>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="button"
                            ng-click="$ctrl.editingTitle = !$ctrl.editingTitle">Edit
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="input-edit" ng-show="$ctrl.editingTitle">
                    <div class="field open">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.knowledgeHubSection.title" maxlength="20">
                    </div>
                    <div class="save-cancel-buttons">
                        <button class="button save-button"
                                ng-click="$ctrl.updateSection()"
                                ng-disabled="$ctrl.isSaving">
                            {[{ $ctrl.isSaving ? $ctrl.submitButtonLabels.submit.saving : $ctrl.submitButtonLabels.submit.idle }]}
                        </button>
                        <button type="button"
                                class="button cancel-button"
                                ng-click="$ctrl.reset()"
                                ng-disabled="$ctrl.isSaving">
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Our application uses the save and cancel buttons in many different views. As such, I want to move that code out views where it used to its own component (we are on AngularJS 1.5) so that I can add the buttons with a component DOM element.

I have done this via the following two files that are accessed by the tag:

```
<ui-save-cancel-component></ui-save-cancel-component>
```

which accesses the following view and component:

```
angular.module('app.admin.ui')
.component(
    'uiSaveCancelComponent', {
        templateUrl: function(UiTemplate) {
            return UiTemplate.EDIT_SAVE_CANCEL;
        },
        bindings: {
            editing: '@'
        },
        require: {
            test: '^knowledgeHubComponent'
        },
        // transclude: true,
        controller: function() {
            'use strict';

            var $ctrl = this;

            $ctrl.submitButtonLabels = {
                submit: {
                    saving: 'Saving',
                    idle: 'Save'
                }
            };

            $ctrl.reset = function() {
                console.log('reset');
                $ctrl.editing = false;
            };


        }
    }
);
```

and

```
<div class="save-cancel-buttons">
   <button class="button save-button"
        ng-click="$ctrl.test.updateSection()"
        ng-disabled="$ctrl.test.isSaving">
    {[{ $ctrl.test.isSaving ? $ctrl.submitButtonLabels.submit.saving : $ctrl.submitButtonLabels.submit.idle }]}
  </button>
  <button type="button"
        class="button cancel-button"
        ng-click="$ctrl.reset()"
        ng-disabled="$ctrl.test.isSaving">
    Cancel
  </button>
</div>
```

The first issue I am having with this solution is that the parent component's name is hardcoded in the component (test: '^knowledgeBaseComponent').  As I want to use this component with other components, how do I make the parent component's name a variable in the `require` of the child?

I thought maybe I could pass the parent's name as an attribute: `<ui-save-cancel-component parent="knowledgeHubComponent"></ui-save-cancel-component>` and in the child component as:

```
bindings: { parent: '@' },
require: { parent: parent }
```

This did not work.

So the question is how do I dynamically 'pass' the parent component to the child component so that I can use the child throughout the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add bindings for save/cancel-callbacks on your button component, so it'll look somewhat like this (I've stripped it down to bare minimum to emphasize my changes):

```
angular.module('app.admin.ui').component(
    'uiSaveCancelComponent', {
        template: [
            '<div>',
             '<button ng-click="$ctrl.onSave()">Save</button>',
             '<button ng-click="$ctrl.onCancel()">Cancel</button>',
            '</div>'
            ].join(''),
        bindings: {
          onSave: '&',
          onCancel: '&'
        }
    }
);
```

Then in your parent-component, you can pass on the callbacks like this:

```
<ui-save-cancel-component 
    on-save="$ctrl.updateSection()" 
    on-cancel="$ctrl.reset()"></ui-save-cancel-component>
```

[Here's a plunker where you can see it in action](https://embed.plnkr.co/45z64IxTQSefDFaYakeX/)

Only passing what is necessary from the parent component, will make your button component a lot more reusable, since it doesn't have to know anything about the components that use it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your recommendation inspired further decoupling in my code.  Again, thanks!